# Azure OpenAI models being unable to correctly identify model

Tags: azure, azure-openai, azure-ai

In Azure OpenAI Studio, while I am able to deploy a GPT-4 instance, the responses are based solely on GPT-3.5 Turbo. I test the same prompts  in my personal ChatGPT sub and it returns the correct response from a GPT-4-based model. Any thoughts?

Comment: Wondering if you selected GPT-4 model from the list of deployed models in Azure OpenAI studio?

Comment: what do you mean by "unable to correctly identify model"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The model is performing next token prediction in response to your question. The model doesn't have any native ability to query what model version is currently being run to answer your question. To answer this question, you can always go to Azure OpenAI Studio > Management > Deployments > and consult the model name column to confirm what model is currently associated with a given deployment name.

To answer your question, you can always go to Azure Open AI studio>Management> Deployments>and consult the model name column to confirm what model is currently associated with a given deployment name.

Here is the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/openai/faq#when-i-ask-gpt-4-which-model-it-s-running--it-tells-me-it-s-running-gpt-3--why-does-this-happen-) that could help.